# How to find a specific month by entering the number of the month and the year as integers?

Tags: java

I have homework that involves the user entering 2 integers (The month & The year) and I was wondering how to do that, I have searched a little in the calendar class documentation but I didn't find what I was searching for. 
The main thing I'm tring to do is to print a calendar like the one in Windows where the only input I get from the user is the number of the month and year, I need to find a way to find weather the month is 31, 30, 29 or 28 days and the day in which that month started.
http://lifehacker.com/assets/2006/06/vista-windows-calendar.jpg this is what I want to do but as text without printing the days from other months .

Comment: Which bit is causing you a problem? It's not clear whether you've already parsed the user input into `int` values, or what you want out as the result...

Comment: You should post what you've tried.

Comment: To expand on @JonSkeet's comment, what exactly do you mean by "find a specific month?" You already have the number of the month and the year it's in -- what further information about it do you need?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `java.util.Date` for this:

```
int month = 3 ; // Input
int year = 2012 ; // Input
Date date = new Date() ;
date.setMonth(month) ;
date.setYear(year) ;
```

But since `Date` is deprecated, you would have to use `java.util.Calendar` instead. The equivalent functions are:

```
Calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month) ;
Calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year) ;
```

Comment: This may be suitable for homework, but the Date class is deprecated for quite a while now.

Comment: Be aware that month here has base 0 (that means Month 1 is February).

Comment: You should rather go with Calendar class.

Comment: Those `Date` methods are deprecated. It is recommended to use `Calendar` instead.

Comment: I edited the question to add some more details, sorry for being unclear :)

Comment: also I can't find the set method in the Calendar class

Comment: you sure u're using `java.util.Calendar`? You can initialize the Calendar object as `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();` Then you'll be able to call `cal.set()`

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I'm not spilling out all the beans. You have to figure out the rest.

Without knowing what have you tried or what do you mean by finding a month, I think you want to obtain a Date object based in a year and a month.

The `Calendar` class was a right start. First of all, you should obtain an instance with the `getInstance()` method, considering the `set(int field, int value)` method in particular to set both the year and the month of that calendar.

If you're wondering how do you know which field you're setting, try the different constant values defined by `Calendar` itself (by convention, those are named in uppercase, just for you to find them).

In the end you just need to obtain that `Date`, through the `getTime()` method.

**EDIT**

Following the `Calendar` class approach and by using set, you can come up with the month you're searching.

Use methods such as `getActualMaximum(int field)` with `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`. That's practically one of the answers. The other one is similar and I'm leaving it up to you.

Hint: Create a calendar and play with the fields, try setting the day of the month to 1 (the first day) and the current month to the one you need to get information from.

Comment: I edited the question to add some more details, sorry for being unclear :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DateFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html). This has methods to retrieve the months. You can then use the index postion in the array (the month number) to get the month

```
   String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault()).getMonths();
   System.out.println(months[0]);
   System.out.println(months[11]);
```

As it's homework I'll let you work out why `[0]` gives Januaray and `[11]` gives December

Comment: +1 for telepathically deducing that he probably wanted the month NAMES... that didn't even occur to me. Since it's homework a better exercise would probably be a switch/case, though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class PrintCalendar {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        int month = 3;
        int year = 2011;

        c.set(year, month, 1); // Set c's time to first day of specified month/year

        // Day of week (by numerical index) can also be obtained programmatically with c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        System.out.println("First day of month falls on a " + new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(c.getTime()));
        // "Actual maximum" means the maximum in the current timeframe; that is, it will return 29 for a February in a leap year
        System.out.println("Month has " + c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " days");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what do these command do "new SimpleDateFormat("EE").format(c.getTime())"

Comment: For that part, you probably really want c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); I edited to add this as a comment. Anyway, what it does is take the time from the Calendar object and format it as a string according to the format string. In this case the format string is "EE" or "EEEE" for the full version, where E is the format code corresponding to day of the week. Google "java SimpleDateFormat" for the docs which will explain it in further detail. Checking out the Calendar docs and some examples will help, too.